# Filter request on proxy_pass using lua on nginx

Tags: nginx, lua

I want to filter streaming url before to streaming server using proxy_pass of nginx with lua

My streaming server is http://localhost:8092

I want to when access to http://localhost:8080/streami1?token=mytoken it will be forward to http://localhost:8092/stream1. If you access to http://localhost:8080/streaming1?token=abc it will be show permission deny page.

It is my code on nginx configuration file:

```
  location ^~ /stream {
            set $flag_false "false";
            set $flag "false";
            set $flag_true 1;
            rewrite_by_lua '
                    local token = ngx.var.arg_token
                    if token == "mytoken" then
                            ngx.var.flag = ngx.var.flag_true
                    end

            ';
            # rewrite_by_lua "ngx.var.flag = ngx.var.flag_true";
            if ($flag = $flag_true) {
                    proxy_pass http://x.x.x.x:8092;
                    break;
            }
            echo "You do not have permission: $flag";
   }
```

But, it not pass to my streaming insteaf of it show "You do not have permission: 1" when i request with url whether http://localhost:8080/streaming1?token=mytoken. Obviously, it change flag value to 1, but it do not pass to my streaming.
What is my wrong?. Please help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The [rewrite_by_lua](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#rewrite_by_lua) directive always runs after the standard [ngx_http_rewrite_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html) (`if` and `set` directives). You can use [set_by_lua](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#set_by_lua) directive instead.
2. The "=" and "!=" operators of `if (condition) {}` statement compare a variable with **a string**, which means `$flag_true` of if-condition will not be evaluated to `1`.

And modified configure is as following:

```
    location ^~ /stream {
        set $flag_true 1;
        set_by_lua $flag '
            local token = ngx.var.arg_token
            if token == "mytoken" then
                return ngx.var.flag_true
            end
            return "false"
        ';
        if ($flag = 1) {
            proxy_pass http://x.x.x.x:8092;
            break;
        }
        echo "You do not have permission: $flag";
    }
```

Comment: What is my problem?. It is right?. Because if(condition) {} statement perform before check token statement?

Comment: @SơnLâm, yes, `if(condition){}` statement performs before check token statement (`rewrite_by_lua`).